# HIVE : Failed to breakup Windowing invocations into Groups. Invalid function LAG

Tags: windows, hive, lag

I'm working in HIVE,

I have a dataset like :

```
client_id       date       nb_pts
        1     2016-06-01        1
        1     2016-06-02        3
        1     2016-06-03        4
        2     2016-06-01        2
        2     2016-06-02        3
```

I need to output for each client, the difference between current nb_pts and previous nb_pts.
So my output should be :

```
client_id       date       nb_pts   nb_pts_per_row
        1     2016-06-01        1                1    (1-0)
        1     2016-06-02        3                2    (3-1)
        1     2016-06-03        4                1    (4-3)
        2     2016-06-01        2                2    (2-0)
        2     2016-06-02        3                1    (3-2)
```

I've tried to use LAG function un HIVE:

```
SELECT client_id, date, nb_pts, 
nb_pts - (LAG(nb_pts, 1, 0) OVER (PARTITION BY client_id ORDER BY date ROWS 1 PRECEDING)) as nb_pts_per_row
FROM MyTable
```

But the validation failed. Its says :

Failed to breakup Windowing invocations into Groups. At least 1 group must only depend on input columns. Also check for circular dependencies. Underlying error: Expecting left window frame boundary for function LAG((TOK_TABLE_OR_COL nb_pts), 1, 0) org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.parse.WindowingSpec$WindowSpec@27a007cd as LAG_window_0 to be unbounded.

EDIT (SOLUTION):

So it works without ROWS 1 PRECEDING :

```
SELECT client_id, date, nb_pts, 
nb_pts - (LAG(nb_pts, 1, 0) OVER (PARTITION BY client_id ORDER BY date)) as nb_pts_per_row
FROM MyTable
```

Comment: `ROWS 1 PRECEDING` makes no sense and should be removed

Comment: remove ROWS 1 PRECEDING and no need to specify 1 row for lag: 

    The number of rows to lag can optionally be specified. If the number of rows to lag is not specified, the lag is one row

Comment: @leftjoin It works without ROWS 1 PRECEDING. Thank you for you help

Comment: @leftjoin, the OP uses a default value (`0`)